# Is Alchemical Alacrity a mistake?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, alchemist

Alchemical Alacrity says:

> Your comfort in concocting items is such that you can create three at a time. When using the Quick Alchemy action, you can spend up to three batches of infused reagents **to make up to three alchemical items** as described in that action. These items do not have to be the same, and you automatically stow one of these new items as you create them.

However, after you use Quick Alchemy for this, you only have 2 remaining actions to throw 2 of the items, and the last one is ruined before you could use it:

> This item has the infused trait, but **it remains potent only until the start of your next turn**.

Theoretically, *if* it is a bomb, *and* you have Quick Bomber *and* you are hasted, you could throw it in the same round, but it is ***very*** circumstantial. Is there any errata for this?

Comment: FWIW, that is an errata'd version of it (originally it didn't say what happened to the 3rd created item).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It really is (mostly) that situational

Speaking with another player in my high-level campaign, whose character is an Alchemist, he can think of no other use for that ability than Quickened Bomber Alchemists.

They further point out that, since it still does splash damage on a non-critical miss (and potentially hit or crit on a nat 20), it's not a complete waste of an action. Before gaining that ability, you would have to expend pre-made alchemical consumables to get 3 attacks in a round.

Additionally, for those who can't immediately use the item, you now have a potentially free (with the Perpetual line of class features) bomb, poison, antiplague or antidote, or mutagen (depending on your Research) that an ally can take off of your belt to use. Again this is very situational, but in the case where there is *suddenly poison everywhere* or you're fighting an enemy that ignores most of an ally's physical damage, they may just be willing to use your scraps.

If you want to capitalize on the action economy, the [Enduring Alchemy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=101) Feat buys you an extra turn to use the resource you made. It's efficacy is dubious (you still officially need an action to take the 3rd item off of your 'worn' items) but it makes Alacrity seem more reasonable. Credit for noting the feat goes to user [Acacia](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/23805/acacia).

Comment: The Enduring Alchemy feat (https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=101) also gives you a bit more time to make use of the items.

Comment: Still I would expect more from a 15th level class ability